# The day bleeds into nightfall

Tags: meaning

My mother tongue is german, recently I heard the words in an english song "the day bleeds into nightfall". 
What does this mean exactly.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Song lyrics are poetry so sometimes words are chosen for artistic reasons and not necessarily the most natural or idiomatic. So, whatever this means, it's probably not the most common way to express it. "What time should we meet for dinner?'" "How about when day bleeds into nightfall?" "Oh. Um. Sorry. I can't make it ...uh... then. How about never? Is never good for you?"

Comment: Wolfgang, have you looked up "bleed into" in a dictionary? For example, one colour can bleed into another. The song merely takes this ordinary meaning and uses it figuratively, which as @Mitch notes, is not unusual in lyrical text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the song of Lewis Capaldi *Someone You Loved* it means the days feel longer (without her).

Answer (score 2):

In 1958, the prestigious American men’s clothing manufacturer Brooks Bros. purchased 10K yards of brightly colored plaid  cotton fabric woven by hand in India. They neglected to warn their customers, however, that the vegetable dyes used in manufacture were not colorfast, and at the first washing, would fade and run together, or [*bleed*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bleed). A Madison Ave. executive transformed the flaw into a fashion feature with a clever slogan — “guaranteed to bleed” — and the [bleeding madras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madras_(cloth)) fashion of the 1960s was born.

[image]

*Source: [Priya Photo](http://priyaphoto.com/editor/?)*

This metaphoric use can be transferred to virtually anything:

> Like every medium, film exceeds itself. It [*bleeds into*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ydd8K4sxsXkC&pg=PA1&dq=%22bleeds+into%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzxazqpO3hAhVN16QKHWLIDnEQ6AEIWDAJ) the meanings of education and public policy, into the landscapes we see when looking out a train window and on the urban streets we walk when killing time. Likewise, Japan— the nation— exceeds itself. It *bleeds into* all that which is not Japan ...  — Eric Cazdyn, Rey Chow, Harry Harootunian,  *The Flash of Capital: Film and Geopolitics in Japan*, 2002, 1.

Including one’s sense of time:

> There isn’t a lot going on, so Monday [*bleeds into*](https://books.google.de/books?id=vFCRJeBhwg4C&pg=PT80&dq=%22bleeds+into%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzxazqpO3hAhVN16QKHWLIDnEQ6AEIOzAE) Tuesday which *bleeds into* Wednesday which *bleeds into* Thursday till all days are one, unending, indistinguishable day. — Sue Halpern, *A Dog Walks Into a Nursing Home*, 2013.

One day bleeding into the next suggests boredom, emptiness, or depression, where nothing else marks the passage of time other than itself.